# Bootstrap works on one server but not another in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin3/ui_colors.html as a theme/template.

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/global/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME STYLES -->
    <link href="/assets/global/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/global/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/admin/layout3/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/admin/layout3/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color">
    <link href="/assets/admin/layout3/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END THEME STYLES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<!-- DOC: Apply "page-header-menu-fixed" class to set the mega menu fixed  -->
<!-- DOC: Apply "page-header-top-fixed" class to set the top menu fixed  -->

<body class="page-header-menu-fixed">
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER TOP -->
        <div class="page-header-top" style="height:150px !important;">
            <div class="container">


                <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
                <div class="top-menu">
                    <h1>Health Intelligence Portal</h1>
                    <h4>Central Southern Commissioning Support Unit</h4>
                    <!--#include virtual="/inc/top-menu-live.inc"-->
                </div>
                <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
                <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler"></a>
                <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
                <div class="page-logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/global/img/central-southern-logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-default">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- END LOGO -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER TOP -->
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER MENU -->
        <div class="page-header-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- BEGIN HEADER SEARCH BOX -->
                <form class="search-form" action="extra_search.html" method="GET">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn submit"><i class="icon-magnifier"></i></a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- END HEADER SEARCH BOX -->
                <!-- BEGIN MEGA MENU -->
                <!--#include virtual="/inc/mega-menu-live.inc"-->
                <!-- END MEGA MENU -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER MENU -->
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <div class="page-container">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEAD -->
        <div class="page-head">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>Welcome to the CSCSU Health Intelligence Portal</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE HEAD -->
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container">


                <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT INNER -->


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        Self Service Portal
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="desc">
                                        Log Calls
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="z-index:1 !important;">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison" style="z-index:0">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        I.T. Forms
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        User Guides &#038; Videos
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        I.T Policies
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-signal"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        Guest Wifi Details
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        Opening Hours
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        Contact Us
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-support"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        Remote Support
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="javascript:;">
                            </p>
                            <div class="dashboard-stat blue-madison">
                                <div class="visual">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <div class="number">
                                        About Us
                                    </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>




                <!-- END PAGE CONTENT INNER -->

                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->


    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <!-- BEGIN PRE-FOOTER -->
    <!--#include virtual="/inc/footer-live.inc"-->
    <!-- END PRE-FOOTER -->
    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <div class="page-footer">
        <div class="container">
            2014 &copy; CSCSU. All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-to-top">
        <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->
    <!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPTS(Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time) -->
    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- IMPORTANT! Load jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js before bootstrap.min.js to fix bootstrap tooltip conflict with jquery ui tooltip -->
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/jquery.cokie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/global/plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
    <script src="/assets/global/scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/admin/layout3/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/admin/layout3/scripts/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            Metronic.init(); // init metronic core components
            Layout.init(); // init current layout
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->

</html>
```

When saved on Server 1, it works fine as shown below in all browsers, and specifically IE8

[image: FIXED]

Now, the exact same code on Server 2 shows the following for IE8 only. Please not just two columns and the search box acting up.

[image: BROKEN]

Developer tools in Chrome and Firefox show no errors. No missing files. No nothing. I got the assets on Server 1 to point to Server 2. Still worked. I got the assets on Server 2 to point to the assets on Server 1, still broken.

Any ideas? Exact same code, on the exact same server setup (Windows 2008 R2). With that said, could IIS be doing something?

Comment: host on both servers and Check the viewsource code for two pages then you can easily find what is changing in servers

Comment: Different HTTP response headers perhaps?

Comment: Some of the files were UTF-8 BOM encoded. Used Notepad++ to remove the BOM.